# Google Cloud Storage for Image - resizing to original size does not work for some images

Tags: image, google-cloud-storage, scaling

I use Google Cloud Storage for images. Images get uploaded to my Google App Engine based server. To serve the images I use the feature that allows image scaling. Just appending =sXXX to the image scales it to the desired XXX size for the largest side. Pecurliar that omitting =sXXX suffix scales to 512 pixels. 
In order to NOT scale, one has to add =s0. This is what I do.

Sometimes, not always, I get this interesting problem. Serving URL uses =s0 suffix to ensure the original image gets download. Here is the example, which works
[bread image, original size, =s0 suffix](http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/x_HkdcY9i53htSKVxk3A9Eo2icUJP4kswQRWKuaDgqoBk3GrPc4AdAfBX8p63pl7oOW9GmGrKCWb5C76BxLYag=s0)

It should work, this is documented in this Google App Engine article: 
[Images Python API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/) and also in this article [Uploading, Resizing and Serving images with Google Cloud Platform](https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556)

However for some images it does not work. Example:
This does not work:
http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Kwj_Fe938vOxsVw9KFILW-MaxoNJlGinxfAHqj4_3bSxhHWPoSLXb5zXGn5k7V4BJgWRlgD1zvULpmjCnFhE1Q=s0

However removing the suffix =s0, shows image all right.

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Kwj_Fe938vOxsVw9KFILW-MaxoNJlGinxfAHqj4_3bSxhHWPoSLXb5zXGn5k7V4BJgWRlgD1zvULpmjCnFhE1Q

At least some other sXXX suffixes work 
http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Kwj_Fe938vOxsVw9KFILW-MaxoNJlGinxfAHqj4_3bSxhHWPoSLXb5zXGn5k7V4BJgWRlgD1zvULpmjCnFhE1Q=s250

So far I have not found a pattern. Looking at [Google's bug repository for Cloud Storage](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559782?p=1) does not reveal anyting useful.

Anyone has an idea where to look?

Comment: [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/73804225) filed on Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Oh, damn, right, sorry about it. After I asked it here I figured it must be a bug and filed it there. The important thing is that they recognized it as a bug and will fix